# Excel formula to find 2nd largest value or largest if only one value

Tags: excel

The formula I have to obtain the 2nd largest value from a range works fine:

```
=LARGE(H9:M9,2)
```

How ever if the range has only one value, i need to return this value as the result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=iferror(LARGE(H9:M9, 2), max(H9:M9))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
=IF(ISERROR(LARGE(H9:M9,2)),LARGE(H9:M9,1),"")
```